# background process|service in android studio

Tags: android, background-process, background-service

I cant find any answers on google cause IDK how to state the problem. I want to know how do you put a background process or function in android which timely do some operations like checking for new notifications, the background process should be working the whole time in any activity, even when application is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this article about [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) . But also, you should read about some limitations that there are especially for Android `Oreo` and above. For example if you have your app closed the OS may kills your `Services`. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) link for `Background Execution Limits` . If you are looking for notifications you should implement a `Service` that extends `MyFirebaseMessagingService` and `override` `onMessageReceived` method. Please check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation on [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground).

**Note:** You need to show a notification in order to launch Foreground Service. And don't forget that your Service is running on UI thread.